# Adding different CSS animations on scroll up and scroll down with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll

I'm trying to add classes when the user scrolls up and down in order to show 2 css animations.

It works well if I'm only using the scroll down animation, but its inconsistent when I use both the scroll up and scroll down animations.

**I'm having problems getting animations to fire multiple times in a row. As in- scroll down pause, scroll down pause, scroll up pause, scroll up pause.**

[Here's a jsFiddle to better demonstrate the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Rj8dJ/88/)

and the code-

```
(function () {
    var previousScroll = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            //down scroll code
            $("#repel").removeClass("climb");
            $("#repel").addClass("repel").delay(1150).queue(function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass("repel");
                next();
            });
        } else {
            // upscroll code
            $("#repel").removeClass("repel");
            $("#repel").addClass("climb").delay(1000).queue(function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass("climb");
                next();
            });
        }
        previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}());
```

Comment: I looked at the jsFiddle but couldn't figure out what you mean with `getting animations to fire multiple times`. I don't really see any animation in the jsFiddle?

Comment: @Jean-Paul sorry I didn't add browser prefixes, the animations are visible in FF at the moment I'll add -webkit- shortly

Comment: Allright, I'll open up my FF then. I'll look into your problem later this evening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out...

I just needed to change the way the animations were being removed. Rather than using a delay and queue I detected the [animation end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/animationend?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/animationend) and removed it that way.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Rj8dJ/90/)**

```
(function () {
    var previousScroll = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            //down scroll code
            $("#repel").addClass("repel");
            $("#repel").on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd', function () {
                $('#repel').removeClass('repel');
            });

        } else {
            // upscroll code
            $("#repel").addClass("climb");
            $("#repel").on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend MSAnimationEnd', function () {
                $('#repel').removeClass('climb');
            });
        }
        previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}());
```